# Chapter name in amsbook

Tags: fancyhdr, amsbook

I use `fancyhdr` to modify the header and footer of a book written with the `amsbook` class. I want the left header on even pages to contain the name of the current chapter, but can't figure out how to do this. The obvious guess to use `\chaptername` does not work (MWE below)

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{CHAPTER~\thechapter~\chaptername}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

does not work.

Comment: `\chaptername` (under English) just contains the word `Chapter`, you probably want to use `\leftmark` or `\rightmark` as that is what `\chapter{title}` normally writes `title` to.

Comment: Yes, I could use leftmark. Leftmark does almost what I want to do, but I don't want a punctuation after the chapter number. So instead of `CHAPTER 1. TITLE`, I would like to have `CHAPTER 1 TITLE`.

Comment: In that case please make sure to provide a full but minimal example such that others have something to work with without having to add stuff just to test your code.

Comment: @daleif Ok, did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redefine `\chaptermark` to get the desired formatting. The `fancyhdr` documentation has several examples of this.

For this case, the following code would probably do what you want.

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\newcommand{\mychaptertitle}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter~#1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\mychaptertitle{#1}}{\mychaptertitle{#1}}}
```

Comment: That's excellent Pieter, many thanks!